# How to quickly enable/disable Javascript in IE like Firefox's Web developer toolbar does?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, internet-explorer

How to quickly enable/disable Javascript in IE like Firefox's Web developer toolbar does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extension for IE 7+ called Developer Tools (already included into beta or preview versions) that have an option to do that, clear cache, etc.

Comment: Will it work in IE6?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to disable javascript on IE6 is through the Internet Options.

Comment: yes  it's workin on IE 6 and 7 both

Answer (score 0):

This recent thread at sitepoint called: [Besides malicious intent, other reasons to disable javascript?](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=646803)
has points that might interest you.
<sup>(look at the [next page](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=646803&page=2) of that thread too).</sup>

[Quote from a Mentor there](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/newreply.php?do=newreply&p=4441130),
I guess others here will be able to comment on these notes.

> Internet Explorer is the one browser that doesn't support JavaScript.
> Instead Internet Explorer supports JScript and VBScript.
>
> JavaScript is close enough to a subset of JScript to be able to write code using feature sensing to detect and handle the differences provided that you start with JavaScript and modify it to work as JScript. There are lots of JScript commands that don't have a Javascript equivalent.
>
> There are a few JavaScript commands that require activeX to work as JScript and those are the areas most vulnerable.
>
> You can't disable JavaScript in IE because IE doesn't support JavaScript at all.
>
> The main reason for disabling JScript is with IE6 where there are a lot of vulnerabilities in activeX and so you really ought to disable activeX when using that browser so as to plug hundered of known security holes. If you do that then you get an alert that activeX is disabled every time you load a page unless you also turn off active scripting to disable JScript and VBScript. Most of those activeX vulnerabilities were fixed in IE7.
>
> The only browser where client side scripting is a potential security issue is Internet Explorer and that is the one browser where people are least likely to turn off scripting as it is the browser that tends to be most used by people who are least aware of those issues since the easiest way to fix the security issues in old versions of IE is to switch to a different browser.
>
> Since running JavaScript in a modern browser does not have security issues, security is not a reason for disabling JavaScript.

And, I wonder if this story on [IE users warned to disable Javascript](http://www.webuser.co.uk/news/top-stories/431941/ie-users-warned-to-disable-javascript) is related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if changing the javascript setting in IE sets a registry key? If so you could create some toolbar/desktop shortcuts that would set/unset that key.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox's developpers  sadly [removed](https://twitter.com/chrispederick/status/935307139911884800) the APIs that powered "the javascript disable features", so this feature had to be [removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1367161) from the extension "web developer" after firefox 2.0 ...

The last solution is to use Firefox Developer Tools:

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> opens the built in Firefox Developer Tools in
   recent versions of Firefox.
2. And go into parameters <kbd>F1</kbd>: 
   [image: Firefox Developer Tools parameters with help of F1]
3. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> again to close it.